# How can I avoid "No test specified" errors in npm?

Tags: testing, npm

I'm using npm@5.6.0 on Mac High Sierra. I want to run tests that were setup in this [Stratum client project](https://github.com/arnabk/stratum-client). I have run `npm install` successfully.  But when I try and run individual tests, I get the error:

```
no test specified
```

What gives?  I am in the root project directory and the tests are in my "test" folder. Here is what happens:

```
localhost:stratum-client-master davea$ npm install
up to date in 0.381s
localhost:stratum-client-master davea$ npm test test/callbacks.js

> stratum-client@1.0.1 test /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/stratum-client-master
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1 "test/callbacks.js"

Error: no test specified
sh: line 0: exit: too many arguments
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 43):

Try replacing

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha"
},
```

in your `package.json`.

Comment: I get mocha not found error now

Comment: 'mocha' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Mocha needs to be installed first before use, thus please run the below command `npm i mocha` or refer to this doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha

Answer (score 21):

You're outputting exactly what the [package.json file](https://github.com/arnabk/stratum-client/blob/master/package.json) was told to output. Take a peek under `scripts`.

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "int-test": "mocha --require babel-core/register --recursive test"
},
```

Try `int-test`, the other command in there.

*Update: The package link has changed to the following and mocha should be the default test suite. You can run the other script with `npm run bump-version`; the original script above can be run with `npm run int-test`.*

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --recursive test",
  "bump-version": "npm version patch"
},
```

Comment: I did try "npm int-test" as their documentaiton recommended but got the error "Usage: npm <command> ... Did you mean one of these? test install-test" so tthen I migrated to what I had above.

Comment: In order to run a command in the `script` tag, you must specify the `run` subcommand. `npm run int-test`. `npm test` is just a short-hand for `npm run test`. It might be a good idea to replace the `test` command with the `int-test` so that you can run `npm test`.

Answer (score 17):

You didn't specify which testing framework you're using such as `Jest` or `Mocha`.

In case of Jest, add this in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts" : { 
    "test" : "jest" 
 }
```

In the case of `mocha` refer to [@Divyeshpal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401092/6904888)'s answer.

Comment: Hi, i am using Jasmine frame work, instead of jest what i need to add?

Answer (score 9):

The error can be for "exit 1"

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Change it to this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"No test specified\""
},
```

This change works because exit 1 creates an error.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Jest and enzyme for unit testing and you have a jest.config.json config file, you can update your package.json under scripts to the following:

```
"scripts":{    
  "test": "jest --config=./jest.config.json --coverage",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error can be for "exit 1"

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Change it to this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"No test specified\""
},
```

This change worked for me because exit 1 created the error.

Comment: Simple, maybe not the best practice, but it worked for me, **thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

find and make changes in your package.json

"scripts":{
"test":"mocha"
}

Answer (score 0):

add this on your packages.json file:

```
"scripts":{
    "test": "mocha --ui tdd tests/callbacks.js",
}
```

then `npm test` on the console.

Answer (score -2):

Replace
`echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1`
in your
`package.json`
with
`mocha`.